# ANDROID STUDIO > Sqlite, Listview and Onclick basic example

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to build my first app, after having read some tutos. The one I am using is this one: http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-sqlite-database-example/

But in his app, the guy goes through an intermediary step for listing sql records.

I would like my app to do the following:

### MyActivity

A button "Add player", once clicked, brings DisplayMessageActivity where I can save a name in the database

### DisplayMessageActivity

An EditText for the name, three buttons (delete, update, close)
(When clicking on delete, I am brought back to MyActivity)
(When clicking on update, I stay on DisplayMessageActivity)
(When clicking on close, I am brought back to MyActivity))

I managed to build it, navigation between both works, and database inserts works well.

When saving a name, I am back to the first activity, but the list appearing is not updated with the new added name.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="tab.sqltesting.com.myapplication.MyActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Player"
        android:id="@+id/addPlayer"
        android:onClick="addPlayer" />

<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my activity_main.java

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button addPlayer;
    TextView players_Id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        PlayersRepo repo = new PlayersRepo(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playersList = repo.getPlayersList();

                if (playersList.size() != 0) {

                    ListView lv = getListView();

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            players_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.players_Id);
                            String playersId = players_Id.getText().toString();
                            Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                            objIndent.putExtra("players_Id", Integer.parseInt(playersId));
                            startActivity(objIndent);
                        }

                    });

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyActivity.this, playersList, R.layout.list_players_view, new String[]{"id", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.players_Id, R.id.players_name});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Player!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

        addPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlayer);
        addPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.addPlayer)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

I would like to ask for your help, to help me understand what I did wrong.

Please accept my apologizes regarding my missunderstandings.

Thank you very much!

Bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orientation of the `LinearLayout` that contains the `ListView` should be vertical

change

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

with

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Thank you! It did not solve the problem: the list is not updated if I add/update a Player... On the other hand, if, when the app is running, I strike the "Home" button (and leave my app in the background) to browse my phone for whatever, and then re-go to it, the list would be updated. I cannot understand the why's and how's... anyway, thanks for your help! If you have any idea...

Comment: why do you expect something different?

Comment: Hmmm... Initially, activity_main.xml has only an "add" button. I then wanted to list database names below the add button, so that when you add a player in my app, you would see it appearing right after the insert. That is why I "tried" to include the portion of the code beginning by "PlayersRepo repo = new Player..." right under the code " setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);"

Comment: but I have no clue about if it's the correct place, and if this code is enough to do it.

Comment: Ok it works now! I had to add the method void onResume()

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in adding OnResume() method. Here is my final activity class:

```
package tab.sqltesting.com.myapplication;

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button addPlayer;
    TextView players_Id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        addPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlayer);
        addPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.addPlayer)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        PlayersRepo repo = new PlayersRepo(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playersList = repo.getPlayersList();

        if (playersList.size() != 0) {

            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    players_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.players_Id);
                    String playersId = players_Id.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("players_Id", Integer.parseInt(playersId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }

            });

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyActivity.this, playersList, R.layout.list_players_view, new String[]{"id", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.players_Id, R.id.players_name});
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No Player!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following method in your MainActivity, and you will see your data in vertical way when you type save.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentsList = repo.getStudentList();

    if(studentsList.size() != 0){

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                student_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_Id);
                String valAnimalId = student_Id.getText().toString();
                Intent  objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentDetail.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("animalId", valAnimalId);
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,studentsList, R.layout.view_student_entry, new String[] { "id","name"}, new int[] {R.id.student_Id, R.id.student_name});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```